# What's this bracket?

Tags: ceiling, mounting

Has anyone seen this type of bracket before, or have suggestions on what it might be called? The drawing is upside down for the intended usage - basically I want the U-shaped piece on the underside of a joist, and the other piece on the top of a sheet of plywood. My goal is to slide if together to hold the plywood up.

Right now the whole idea is hypothetical - first I need to find the bracket to see what kind of load it could hold.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a TV-wall mounting bracket.

Answer (score 1):

its called a z clip usually, but the socket side is a little different

Comment: "interlocking" z clip might be even better...